# Doing where condition with an array of value in KQL

Tags: arrays, variables, kql

I'm trying so simplify my searches since I'm searching same values in different tables, I want to put the searched values in a table and put it in my where condition can't succeed to do it, I tried with "has_any" operator or "in", I tried several types of variable, can someone help on that :

```
let array= ("AAA","BBB","CCC");

Table
|where Field in(array)

Table1
|where Field1 in (array)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/searchoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer) operator

```
search "AAA" or "BBB" or "CCC"
| summarize count() by $table
```

| $table | count_ |
| --- | --- |
| StormEvents | 69 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAAytOTSxKzlBQcnR0VFLIL1JQcnJygjCcnZ2VuGoUiktzcxOLMqtSFZLzS/NKNDQVkioVVEoSk3JSAWEletw8AAAA)

Comment: Hello, thank you but it's not exactly what I want, it's for investigations in Defender, I need to check if some values matched some fields and need all fields of the row, not just a count and I need to check for those values in several tables/fields that's why I want to put the value to find in an array one time and then, use the array in the query and not copy paste all the values several time

Comment: The summarization is only for demonstration purposes, showing that you get an indication to the tables the results are taken from.  You can do what ever you want with the search results.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array with [pack_array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/packarrayfunction) and use [has_any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/has-anyoperator).

```
let array= pack_array("AAA","BBB","CCC");
StormEvents
| where EpisodeNarrative has_any (array)
| count
```

[Run sample in ADX](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA8tJLVFILCpKrLRVKEhMzo4HszWUHB0dlXSUnJycgKSzs7OSpjVXcEl%20Ua5rWWpeSTFXjUJ5RmpRqoJrQWZxfkqqH0hXSWZZqkJGYnF8Yl6lggbYHE2gwuT80rwSALburFtmAAAA)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, nut I got same error message :

Semantic error
Error message
'where' operator: Failed to resolve table or column or scalar expression named 'loubo'
How to resolve
Fix semantic errors in your query

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement and ended up using the dynamic data type. This will work:

```
let array = dynamic(["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"]);

Table
|where Field in(array)
```

The reason you need to use the dynamic data type in the context of your query is that the `in` operator in Kusto Query Language (KQL) expects the right-hand side to be a dynamic array.